# mongodb : switch to non-existing databases

Tags: mongodb

recently I started learning mongodb,today I find mongo can switch to a db which is not existed.

```
> db
test
> use col
switched to db col
> show dbs
local  0.000GB
test   0.000GB
> show collections
> use test
switched to db test
>
```

as the code shows I typed 'switched to db col',but the db col is not existed,there is no warning or error,why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/mongo/)

> You can switch to non-existing databases. When you first store data in
>   the database, such as by creating a collection, MongoDB creates the
>   database. For example, the following creates both the database
>   myNewDatabase and the collection myCollection during the insert()
>   operation:

```
use myNewDatabase
db.myCollection.insert( { x: 1 } );
```

`db` refers to the current database.
`myCollection` is the name of the collection.

Comment: This is really convenience and interesting

Comment: It would be nice if it gave some notice/warning that you were switching a non-existing db... I made a typo while switching and thought I had somehow deleted everything in my db when I tried to query my collections